# Woocommerce backorder notification in checkout page

Tags: php, filter, woocommerce, conditional-statements, action

I am trying to add an action that will check whether or not a product that is currently only available on back order is being checked out - and in the case that **one or more is**, I want to display a message before the checkout form.

I've gotten this far:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'wnd_checkout_message', 10 );
function wnd_checkout_message( ) {
echo '<div class="wnd-checkout-message"><h3>The message goes here!</h3></div>';}
```

But how do I check whether or not a back ordered product is currently being checked out/is in the cart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code to your functions.php file. It will show a notice if one of the products in your cart is on backorder.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'es_checkout_add_cart_notice' );

function es_checkout_add_cart_notice() {
    $message = "You have a backorder product in your cart.";

    if ( es_check_cart_has_backorder_product() ) 
        wc_add_notice( $message, 'error' );

}

function es_check_cart_has_backorder_product() {
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $cart_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id() );

        if( $cart_product->is_on_backorder() )
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: @W4yp01nt not a problem, please accept my answer and I will be most grateful :)

Comment: Andrew, quick question, if I wanted to add the same string (conditionally, aswell) to the top of the "Processing order" e-mail, is there a way this code can be modified to accommodate that?

Comment: You can see a list of hooks for emails here https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-emails/

Comment: @W4yp01nt I revised my answer and added use of the function wc_add_notice()

Comment: Hello @Andrew, it seems as if your revision removed all notifications? Also, am I wrong in assuming that the reason why I can't get this to display in the e-mail, is because it is essentially trying to check the status of products in a cart that effectively does not exist at that point? (the point of e-mail creation), I tried hooking all the e-mail filters, I simply can't get it to display.

Thank you for all your help so far, for now I will stick to the string that creates a div in the checkout page :-)

Comment: @W4yp01nt You can still access the product information at any point in the order process.  The notifications are still appearing for me on my test server with this new code.  If it doesn't work for you then revert back to the other version which will still work but not the best way of doing it.

Comment: I assume that the notice should also be displayed when part of the selected quantity is on backorder. The current code does not show a notice in this case. To achieve this, I changed the code inside the foreach loop to:
`$cart_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id() );
  $quantity = $values['quantity'];
        if( $quantity > $cart_product->get_stock_quantity() )
            return true`